# bookmark in NSMutableIndexSet

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

Trying to save bookmark page in NSMutableIndexSet, when button is tapped it changes the bookmarkButton image, when page is flipped it updates the bookmarkButton image but when i go back to the bookmarked page to check the bookmark page, it doesn't  shows the Bookmark-Y image on the bookmarked page. Which means it is not saving the bookmarked page. How can i fix that

```
 - (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

if(isFirstTime == YES){

  [_bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [self performSelector:@selector(SaveBookmark:) withObject:contentViewController.page afterDelay:0];

  isFirstTime = NO;

} else {

   [_bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    isFirstTime = YES;
}
       }

- (void)SaveBookmark: (id)sender{

bookmarkIndex =[[NSMutableIndexSet indexSet] init];

[bookmarkIndex addIndex:currentIndex];

 BOOL Bookmarked = [bookmarkIndex containsIndex:currentIndex];
 }


 - (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{

if (!completed)
{
    return;
}
currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:contentViewController.page];

[self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex];

[self updatebookmarks:currentIndex];

 }


- (void) updatebookmarks:(NSUInteger)currentIndex {
if (Bookmarked==YES){


    [_bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

} else {
  [_bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
   }
```

Any idea what i m doing wrong in saving bookmark in NSMutableIndexSet. Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you initializing your `NSMutableIndexSet` every time you need to save it? (`bookmarkIndex =[[NSMutableIndexSet indexSet] init];`) You might be losing all the content at each save.

Comment: If i initialize it in viewdidload and only adding index in bookmarkIndex still having same problem

Comment: Ok. Now, in `SaveBookmark:`, why are you re-declaring `BOOL Bookmarked`, which *seems* to be an instance variable at the same time? I'm not sure but the fact that you are declaring it here again might override the instance variable (no Xcode warning here?).

Comment: if i remove the bool bookmarked then it is showing all pages with Bookmark-Y.png image which is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues here. I'll try to address all of them:

`bookmarkIndex = [[NSMutableIndexSet indexSet] init];` *- This is incorrect*

It should be either: `[NSMutableIndexSet indexSet]` OR `[[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init]`

Next, as @Romain said, you should be initializing this as a property in your class initialization or viewDidLoad method, regardless of if it solves this problem or not. You should not be re-initializing the set every time you add to it.

Next, I'm not sure why you are using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay when you call the save method. Is there some reason for this? A better way to create your saveBookmark method would be like this:

```
- (BOOL)saveBookmark
{
   if (!bookmarkIndex) {
      bookmarkIndex = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
   }
   if (currentIndex) {
      [bookmarkIndex addIndex:currentIndex];
      return [bookmarkIndex containsIndex:currentIndex];
   }
   return NO;
}
```

This way you can check the return value of your saveBookmark method. If it is returning 'NO' then you know something is wrong with currentIndex or your bookmarkIndex variable is being affected by another part of your program in a negative way. In your buttonTapped: method you would then save a bookmark like this:

```
if (isFirstTime == YES) {
   [_bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   if ([self saveBookmark]) {
      isFirstTime = NO;
   } else {
      NSLog(@"There was an error saving the bookmark");
   }
} else {  ...code continues
```

If nothing else, this should at least help you to diagnose the issue and track down your problem!

EDIT:

If you use the code above, you are effectively disabling the use of that boolean value to determine if the page is bookmarked or not. In your updateBookmarks: method call you should be checking the bookmarkIndex set for the current index like this:

```
- (void) updatebookmarks:(NSUInteger)currentIndex {
   if ([bookmarkIndex containsIndex:currentIndex]) {
      [_bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   } else {
      [_bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. Appreciate that. Let me try it.

Comment: i tried this it doesn't shows me that there was an error in saving the bookmark but when i flip back pages to check on bookmarked page still it doesn't shows Bookmark-Y.png image on the bookmarked page to show that is is bookmarked.

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. I want to give you more points but i can't. Appreciate so much for your help.

Comment: still it has one issue like when i flip pages and go back to check on bookmarks it shows bookmarked pages which is right. but when i totally exit and comeback again then it is not showing those bookmarked pages. how I can fix this.

Comment: The bookmarkIndex is only saved while the app is running. You would need to save it somewhere using Core Data, plists, etc. if you want the bookmarkIndex set to persist between app runs. See this apple doc for plist storage: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i